# Will jQuery document ready wait for html elements injected dynamically through Backbone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, single-page-application, document-ready

My code is a JS module that is plugged into an SPA whose code I cannot control. This SPA uses Backbone to load HTML elements dynamically from a template. One of those elements is a div which I need in my code. I am looking for it in jQuery's document ready..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($( "#myDivId" )[0] != undefined) {
      console.debug("Found it");
   } else {
      console.debug("D'OH!");
   }
});
```

Sometimes I find that div and other times I don't. This leads me to believe that DOM ready doesn't always wait for Backbone. Can you confirm this?

And if such is the case, then are there any other event handlers I can place my code where it always find Backbone's dynamically inserted HTML?

Comment: I think it is safe to assume if you are not finding the div sometimes it is not waiting for it. I don't use backbone, but you can give .load a shot, see if that works.

Comment: No. Document ready fires when the DOM as defined in the markup has loaded. It does not wait for asynchronous JS library loading to complete - nor any dynamic JS elements to be added from other libraries. You could always write your own callback to load your jQuery init once Backbone is done doing its thing but this could be problematic if you are trying to do any manipulation before the dynamic elements are loaded.

Comment: @Korgrue, could you give a code example of that callback that can fire once Backbone is done, and if Backbone is done then all dynamic elements should already be loaded at that point right?

Comment: @AbuMariam there is no such thing. One of your views may load another view after an AJAX call which takes few minutes, and it might create a bunch of views that creates another views... and so on.  `ready` is totally dependent on your application and you have to define when you're app is considered "done" loading stuff.

Comment: As @AbuMariam noted - there is no built in callback functionality. It is something that you would have to write. 

Instead of using the jQuery ready function, you could instead just put your dom manipulation functions into an `init()` function that is called when a specific event happens. IE. if you are pulling content in dynamically - you can tie the init() call to something like an AJAX request  (this is just an example since I dont know what your code looks like in order to piggyback on a function that already has a callback).

Comment: Ideally, you want to pull in any partials or dynamic content BEFORE calling `init()` - rather than depending on jQuery `ready`. This will prevent forcing the browser to recalculate, reposition, and repaint the screen as well as ensuring your elements are actually in the DOM before trying to access them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As confirmed by Korgrue and others, jQuery ready function can not be relied on to tell me when Backbone is done inserting stuff into the DOM, so also as suggested by Korgrue my solution is to have my own init() function that the Backbone app can call when its done adding divs to the DOM. This way I can be sure the div I need will always be there.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: No, document ready does not wait for backbone. I can confirm this.

> are there any other event handlers I can place my code where it always find Backbone's dynamically inserted HTML?

Yes- If your view creates it's own element, right after you add the view to DOM, You know it's in DOM. Backbone doesn't do it, you are the one adding it to DOM so you know when you do it.

If you view points to an existing element in DOM, well that element is already in DOM, you can do whatever you want in view.

So the point is - it's you who controls when stuff gets added to DOM and when to query stuff from DOM.

Comment: as I said in my original question, my code is only a module which is plugged into a Backbone app (whose code is someone else's). So its not my code which is inserting the div but it needs to read the div that someone else's code put. I just wanted to know if I can rely on document ready to let me know when that Backbone app is done putting stuff in the DOM but you confirmed that I can't. Thanks for that!